# Can't install fail2ban on CentOS 6.9

Tags: centos, fail2ban

I can't install `fail2ban` on my CentOS 6.9. Here is my config

```
# cat /etc/*release

CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

# rpm -q epel-release
epel-release-6-8.noarch
```

My installation log

```
# yum install fail2ban
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.awanti.com
* epel: ftp.nluug.nl
* extras: mirror.awanti.com
* rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
* updates: mirror.awanti.com
* webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fail2ban.noarch 0:0.9.7-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: fail2ban-server = 0.9.7-1.el7 for package: fail2ban-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: fail2ban-sendmail = 0.9.7-1.el7 for package: fail2ban-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: fail2ban-firewalld = 0.9.7-1.el7 for package: fail2ban-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fail2ban-firewalld.noarch 0:0.9.7-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: firewalld for package: fail2ban-firewalld-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch
---> Package fail2ban-sendmail.noarch 0:0.9.7-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package fail2ban-server.noarch 0:0.9.7-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.7 for package: fail2ban-server-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-python for package: fail2ban-server-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: fail2ban-server-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: fail2ban-server-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: fail2ban-server-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
       Installed: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (@base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python34-3.4.9-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           python(abi) = 3.4
       Available: python36-3.6.6-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           python(abi) = 3.6
           python(abi) = 3.6
Error: Package: fail2ban-server-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: systemd-python
Error: Package: fail2ban-firewalld-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: firewalld
Error: Package: fail2ban-server-0.9.7-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: systemd
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

My Python log

```
# python -V
Python 2.6.6

# python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.6
```

UPD: Solved with installation `python-boto` before `fail2ban`

```
yum install python-boto
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible update the python package to python36 from epel before installing fail2ban.

Comment: see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

it appears to have been a cache issue, as the issue was solved after running the following command:

```
yum clean all; yum makecache
```